# Powershell Error Re: M$ Advice Thread (Windows 10 Start Menu Suddenly very slow. Also Firefox (not other browsers) Fresh 'Reset' of Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell, start-menu, windows-search

I had to 'Reset' my Windows and I opted to 'keep my files'. I did Disk Cleanup to remove the old.windows files.

Before I had the problem, Windows was extremely snappy and quick even after a year or more of being installed. The problem was caused after I installed an app made by ASRock which was able to play with clock values etc and it completely bugged my machine so I couldn't use it, I found it easiest to try a reset of Windows.

Long story short, it is slow now BUT only when clicking the Start Menu and/or searching for app etc in taskbar. Everything else is quick. Temps are perfect, games run perfectly, 4k video etc etc.

I read this thread: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start-winpc/start-menu-wont-open-windows-10-is-suddenly/4ea92f23-5680-4d3e-93a8-4c0aa7bc49b7

It basically got me to type this into Powershell:

`Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers |Where-Object {$_.InstallLocation -like "*SystemApps*"} | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}`

He says if this process fails, I either typed incorrectly or have a LARGE problem with Windows. Seeing as I've typed/pasted this several times, and I downloaded Windows directly from Microsoft, I don't see what I can do next. I receive this error in Powershell telling me that I need to close Windows Client and WindowsStartMenu (or something...):

```
ERROR: 
Add-AppxPackage : Deployment failed with HRESULT: 0x80073D02, The package could not be installed because resources it   modifies are currently in use.                                                                                          error 0x80073D02: Unable to install because the following apps need to be closed                                        Microsoft.Windows.StartMenuExperienceHost_10.0.19041.610_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy.                                 NOTE: For additional information, look for [ActivityId] 46500a1d-382a-0000-e571-56462a38d701 in the Event Log or use    the command line Get-AppPackageLog -ActivityID 46500a1d-382a-0000-e571-56462a38d701                                     At line:1 char:94                                                                                                       + ...  | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.I ...                                         +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                                                 + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (C:\Windows\Syst...ppXManifest.xml:String) [Add-AppxPackage], Exception         + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DeploymentError,Microsoft.Windows.Appx.PackageManager.Commands.AddAppxPackageCommand                                                                                                                              Add-AppxPackage : Deployment failed with HRESULT: 0x80073D02, The package could not be installed because resources it   modifies are currently in use.                                                                                          error 0x80073D02: Unable to install because the following apps need to be closed
MicrosoftWindows.Client.CBS_120.2212.551.0_x64__cw5n1h2txyewy.
NOTE: For additional information, look for [ActivityId] 46500a1d-382a-0006-577e-51462a38d701 in the Event Log or use
the command line Get-AppPackageLog -ActivityID 46500a1d-382a-0006-577e-51462a38d701
At line:1 char:94
+ ...  | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.I ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (C:\Windows\Syst...ppXManifest.xml:String) [Add-AppxPackage], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DeploymentError,Microsoft.Windows.Appx.PackageManager.Commands.AddAppxPackageCommand
```

Comment: The command you used solves an entirely different problem with the start menu.  You have indicated the start menu opens but is extremely slow, while that thread describes a problem, where the start menu doesn’t open at all.  The errors that are happening are to be expected, you are attempting to register UWP applications, while they are actively being used.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is there any other way to 'restore' or otherwise test the functionality of the start menu. It is always slow and never used to be this way. I tried fiddling with Search Indexing and Cortana settings to no avail.

Comment: You can make a new user to see if it’s limited to a single logon or not

Comment: @Ramhound I must have read your mind. Because coincidentally I just made a new local account and its all very fast again. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Gets downvoted for asking genuine question.... maybe I should use a different website for help next time. Thanks anyway all

Comment: You shouldn’t get upset over a single downvote.  However, creating the test user, was to verify if the problem was the user profile or something else.  Now you have confirmed the issue is the user profile, can you verify the problem, exists within safe mode.

Comment: I am not upset at all. But every question I ask here (and other StackExchange sites) seems to have same issues. No big deal but mindboggling the mentality of some people.

Comment: @Ramhound I did try yesterday to startup in Safe Mode and the problem had persisted. It would be lovely to find a way to refresh my current user account as right now I am planning how to reinstall my dev environment etc and other apps and shortcuts I had set up

Comment: This is the only question here at Super User that has received a downvote.

Comment: I've had more than one account but cannot access the emails any longer so had to make new one. Similar story over many years with the other 'SE' sites -let's not dwell on it though (although I truly fail to see the need for a downvote here but whatever :D )

Comment: Really odd that both Firefox and Start Menu are fast in the new account. Edge, Opera etc were still fast in the 'bugged' account. So this problem somehow affected both Firefox, the Start button, and Windows Search it seems. (They all work perfectly on new account)

Comment: It’s not that odd.  Anyway, you are running 2004 or higher?

Comment: sorry i misunderstand the question. 2004 version of what? I have latest Windows 10 with all updates (I downloaded it directly from Microsoft about 2 weeks ago and updated as soon as installed). The same for Firefox is all the latest. AFAIK I also have the latest version of all drivers for each component/device in the PC.

Comment: You can have Windows 10 version 1507 and have all updates installed. I am asking what version of Windows you have installed.

Comment: Ah i see :D Windows 10 Pro, Version 20H2, OS build 19042.928, Experience Pack 120.2212.551.0, Installed on 3/4/21. (This is from the old 'bugged' account System>About menu).

Comment: Give me a little while to test something out.

Comment: Thank you, your help is very much appreciated here. Even if we don't find any solution, its very kind of you for trying.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new user account made everything work correctly and fast again.

Strange that  this was necessary on a fresh 'reset' install of Windows, but at least this has fixed it.